# frame background colour

Tags: java

**how to give background colour in a frame using java swing?**

Comment: Did you try looking at the javadocs? :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try JComponent.[setBackground(Color c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBackground%28java.awt.Color%29)?

Answer (score 0):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Top Level Container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html). It explains the structure of the frame. In general the "content pane" is used to hold the components you add to the frame. So you need to set the background of the content pane, not the frame.